# removing previous content from datagridview after new search

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I am writing a small form that does a query (queries may have different results in terms of columns) over a SQLite database and display results over a datagridview, via a datatable in vb.net

Everything works fine, the only problem comes when I do a new search, the new results are appended to the old ones.

What can I do to actually reset the datatable/datagridview and display only the new results?

I already tried commands like datatable.Clear(), but with this, when doing a new search, I get only the table headers and no results

Any hint?

Comment: I usually use this and it Works: CType(MyDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).Clear() does not work for you?

Comment: Hi Aldipa, I tried but I get A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Comment: Hi @Alekx3, that makes sense if  the grid's datasource has not been assigned, I would then Use something like this: `If Not Me.MyDataGridView.DataSource Is Nothing Then
                CType(MyDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).Clear()
            End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these three steps:

```
'step 1: fill DataSet
Dim dsYourDataSet As New DataSet("YourDataSet")
Dim daYourDataSet As New SqlDataAdapter(strYourSQLQuery, conn)
dsYourDataSet.Clear()
daYourDataSet.Fill(dsYourDataSet, "YourDataSet")

'step 2: delete every column in DataGridView
Me.dgvYourDataGridView.Columns.Clear()

'set 3: set DataSource of DataGridView
Me.dgvBolle.DataSource = dsBolla.Tables("YourDataSet")
```

The same result can be obtained using a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linq, and I let the datagridview datasource be updated everytime with the same sql string.  I don't get the appends, since the datasource starts from 0 and fills everything in.

```
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = db.getSpareParts(cbox0043.Checked, cboxOnderSS.Checked, txtYnumber.Text, txtDescription.Text, cboxType.Text, cboxLocation.Text)
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Y-nummer"
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 65
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Omschrijving"
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width = 200
```

and so on...

where

```
Public Function getSpareParts(ByVal blnonstock As Boolean, ByVal blnunderSS As Boolean, Optional ynumber As String = "", Optional description As String = "", Optional type As String = "", Optional location As String = "") As IEnumerable
    Try
        Dim db = New DCDataContext
        Dim expr As IEnumerable = From spare In db.tblSpareParts Where spare.SparePartDeleted = False And If(ynumber = "", spare.SparePartDeleted = False, spare.SparePartYnumber.Contains(ynumber)) And If(description = "", spare.SparePartDeleted = False, spare.SparePartDescription.Contains(description) Or spare.SparePartRemarks.Contains(description)) And If(type = "", spare.SparePartDeleted = False, type = spare.SparePartType) And If(location = "", spare.SparePartDeleted = False, location = spare.SparePartLocation) And If(blnonstock = True, spare.SparePartLocation.StartsWith("0"), spare.SparePartDeleted = False) And If(blnunderSS = False, spare.SparePartDeleted = False, spare.SparePartCurrentStock < spare.SparePartMinimumStock)
        Select spare.SparePartYnumber, spare.SparePartDescription, spare.SparePartLocation, spare.SparePartType, spare.SparePartCurrentStock, spare.SparePartMinimumStock, spare.SparePartPrice, spare.SparePartRemarks, spare.SparePartLastModified, spare.SparePartUserName Order By SparePartYnumber Take 750
        Return expr
    Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```